# Three.js getObjectByName objloader

Tags: javascript, three.js

Trying for weeks to access OBJLOADED objects in a three.js scene to translate and rotate by keyboard buttons. For example, typing letter 'A' will translateX objA and 'B' translateX objB.

```
function addObject(model) {
   var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
   var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();

   mtlLoader.load(model+'.mtl', function (materials) {
    materials.preload();       
    objLoader.setMaterials(materials);

    objLoader.load(model+'.obj', function (object) {        
        object.name =model;
        scene.add(object);        
        // how do I return an object?
    });
});
}   

var obj1 = scene.getObjectByName('objA');

if(obj1.name=='objA'){
    alert('Yes');
}
```

This is not working. Ideas, please?

Answer (score 0):

Just create a map where you store your objects, you want to interact with.

```js
var myObjs = {};

function addObject(model) {
   var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
   var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();

   mtlLoader.load(model+'.mtl', function (materials) {
    materials.preload();       
    objLoader.setMaterials(materials);

    objLoader.load(model+'.obj', function (object) {        
        object.name = model;
        scene.add(object);        

        myObjs[model] = object;
    });
  });
}

addObject('objA');
addObject('objB');

function onKeyUp(event) {
    switch(event.keyCode) {
        case 65:
            myObjs['objA'].translateX(1);
            break;
        case 66:
            myObjs['objB'].translateX(1);
            break;
    }
}

window.addEventListener('keyup', onKeyUp);
```